# Axis2/Rampart and WCF

Tags: .net, wcf, apache-axis, ws-security, rampart

I'm trying to setup a client using Axis2/Rampart to create a WS-Security call to a WCF .net service hosted by my client.

My client is receiving the error:
'The message received over Transport security has unsigned 'To' header.'

Does anyone have any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Looks like WS-Addressing problem. Do you know how is WCF service configured? Do you have WSDL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Needed to specify e.g.

```
<signatureParts>{Element}{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}To</signatureParts>
```